# Don't click on screen when click a model

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I created a modal in HTML, but when i click button, i can't close popup display
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG2GM.png)

code

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="false">
    Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Content
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding z-index for the modal-content

```
<div class="modal-content" style="z-index:9999">
```

Comment: i can't fix it :(